# mongoDB delete from array

Tags: json, mongodb

I am wondering how I can delete certain elements from an array in mongoDB.
I have the following json saved in the collection `geojsons`:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "ID": "1753242",
        "TYPE": "8003"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "ID": "4823034",
        "TYPE": "7005"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "ID": "4823034",
        "TYPE": "8003"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to delete every element in the array `features`, where `properties.TYPE` equals `8003`.
I tried it with the following statement, but it does not delete anything.

```
db.geojsons.aggregate([
{$match: {'features': {$elemMatch : {"properties.TYPE": '8003' }}}},
{$project: {
    features: {$filter: {
        input: '$features',
        as: 'feature',
        cond: {$eq: ['$$feature.properties.TYPE', '8003']}
    }}
}}
])
.forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.features.forEach(function(feature) {
        db.collection.deleteOne(
            { "feature.properties.TYPE": "8003"  }            
        );
        print( "in ")
    });
});
```

Does anybody know, why this does not delete anything or how to delete the matching elements?
For me it seems that the failure is inside the `forEach`, since the print statement gets executed as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of `aggregation` here, you can use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) of [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

```
db.geojsons.update(
   { "type": "FeatureCollection" }, //or any matching criteria
   {$pull: { "features": { "properties.TYPE": "8003"} }}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) to delete specific elements from the array

```
db.geojsons.update({}, {
      $pull: {features: {'properties.TYPE':'8003'}}
    }, {multi:true})
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess in this case the correct solution is reading the matching documents, modify and save them again. So simply create a search query that matches the documents you want: remove the elements in the array that you don't want and save it again.

Moreover, this statement is not doing what you want:

```
db.collection.deleteOne(
    { "feature.properties.TYPE": "8003"  }            
);
```

In fact it is searching for a document that has structure such that  feature.properties.TYPE matches it like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": {
      "properties": {
        "TYPE": "8003"
      }
    }
}
```

And this is definitely not the structure you have.