# MongoDb remove element from array as sub property

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to remove an entry in an array that is a sub property of a document field.
The data for a document looks like this:

```
{
    _id: 'user1',
    feature: {
        enabled: true,
        history: [
            {
                _id: 'abc123'
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

For some reason I have not been able to remove the element using $pull and I'm not sure what is wrong.

I've looked at the [official docs for `$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull), this [well-known answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb), as well [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543949/mongodb-delete-from-array).

I have tried the following query

```
db.getCollection('userData').update({ _id:'user1' }, {
    $pull: {
        'feature.history': { _id: 'abc123' }
    }
})
```

and it has no effect. I've double-checked `_id` and it is a proper match. I've also tried filtering based on the same entry, thinking I need to target the data I'm trying to remove:

```
db.getCollection('userData')
    .update({ _id: 'user1', 'feature.history': { _id: 'abc123' }, { ... })
```

So far no luck

Comment: what is the type of the `_id`? because if it is objectId then you need to cast your id

Comment: it's a mongodb `ObjectId`. How should it be cast?

Comment: `$pull: {
        'feature.history': { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('your_id_field') }
    }` Try this

Comment: that was it. I thought mongodb implicitly converted `_id` fields when querying, but using `ObjectId()` in my original query modified the record successfully. Thanks! Can you add this as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast your `id` to mongoose ObjectId

```
db.getCollection('userData').update(
   { "_id": "user1" },
   { "$pull": { "feature.history": { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(your_id) } }
})
```

Comment: The source of the issue is that I was passing the `_id` through a socket.io message, causing it to turn into a string in the back end. I am not using mongoose, but using the mongo type worked successfully: `const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId` and later `_id: ObjectId('..')`

Comment: Ok I got it what was the issue here... There is not need to cast if you would have used mongoose... But in mongodb queries you have to cast it

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('userData').update({ _id:'user1', "feature.history._id" : "abc123" }, {
    $pull: {
        'feature.history.$._id': 'abc123'
    }
})
```